# Проблема в java конструкторe Java

Tags: java, конструктор

Код компилируется но выдаёт ошибки(

```
package com.company;

public class BoolVector {
int size; // размер вектора
int[] arr = new int[size]; // элементы вектора
BoolVector(int size)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Введите число");
        arr[i]=10;
    }
 }
}
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BoolVector A = new BoolVector(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(A.arr[i]);
    }
    return;
 }
}
```

Вот что выдаёт компилятор:

> Введите число
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>
> at com.company.BoolVector.(BoolVector.java:15)
> at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:10)

Answer (score 2):

```
BoolVector(int size)
{
    arr = new int[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Введите число");
        arr[i]=10;
    }
 }
}
```

Размер массива равен нулю. Его нужно создавать после передачи размера